# Is there a User Control Library project type in VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, user-controls, custom-controls

I was looking for it all night, but it seems that the project type is not on vs 2010.

But the main problem is, I want to make a custom control (or a user control compiled to a dll, if vs 2010 does not have the custom control library feature).
Unluckily, I was not able to find any article for 2010 but only for 2008, which is pretty much different from the 2010 IDE.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479318.aspx#customcontrolfromusercontrol_topic3

How will I be able to create a custom control in vs2010? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

It seems there are big differences between VS2005 and VS2010 concerning ascx controls. Most of the solutions I found while researching this problem for a project I'm working on deal with VS2005 and cannot be translated to VS2010.

However, I found and described a solution on my blog ([introduction](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/creating-asp-net-user-control-libraries-in-visual-studio-2010/), [implementation](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/02/11/migration-asp-net-user-controls-to-a-dll-in-visual-studio-2010/)) to implement User Control libraries in VS2010.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the process listed in that article?  It should still work in VS2010.  I'm surprised Microsoft recommends that process, however.  It's a bit of a hack.  I've tried it in the past and found it unreliable.

Comment: Some of the steps on this article are not applicable to vs 2010 (or they might have a different way of doing it, but are not listed so).
Thanks for the response =)